# Vue/Webpack fails to compile image

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I've searched around and applied all kinds of methods but still can't get Webpack and Vue to successfully compile an image asset addressed in a .vue file.

I've tried fiddling with file-loader, url-loader, different ways of referencing the image and importing left and right, even if it doesn't show in the code below. I figured I should ask to get a conclusive and educational answer.

Note that everything works just fine when the image is removed from the code.

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-8959d626","hasScoped":false,"optionsId":"0","buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/js/component.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/img/test.jpg' in 'D:\Projects\Web\src\js'
 @ ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-8959d626","hasScoped":false,"optionsId":"0","buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/js/component.vue 28:27-59
 @ ./src/js/component.vue
 @ ./src/js/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/js/main.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

**component.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
<img src="./assets/img/test.jpg">
</div>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import component from './component.vue';

Vue.config.devtools = true;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [{
    path: '/component',
    component: component
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    publicPath: '/public/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          // `vue-loader` options
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
};
```

**File structure**

```
 src
  - assets
  -- img
  --- test.jpg
  - js
  -- component.vue
  -- main.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path must be relative. Since you are at `js` folder, you must navigate up using `..`:

```
<img src="../assets/img/test.jpg">
```

#### Breakdown:

It's just like regular folder navigation. Since the `<template>` is at `src/js/component.vue`, to get to `test.jpg`, you do:

- Initial file: `src/js/component.vue`
- Starting folder: `src/js/`

  - `../` now you are at `src/`
  - `../assets` now you are at `src/assets`
  - `../assets/img` now you are at `src/assets/img`
  - `../assets/imgtest.jpg` now you get `src/assets/img/test.jpg`

### Reference:

As pointed by [@AkinHwan in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481294/vue-webpack-fails-to-compile-image#comment86869431_49481361), a great resource/reference for the assets behaviors is **https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html**

Comment: Strangely enough this, which I had tried multiple times, didn't work when I was already running the dev server, but if I restarted the project and ran it again it successfully compiled. Thanks for the help!

Comment: these docs helped me learn more about what webpack is doing being the scenes with assets https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Comment: @AkinHwan Great reference indeed. I have added to the question as an edit. Thanks a lot for pointing out.